# Unit Testing AndroidViewModel classes

Tags: android, unit-testing

Im writting Unit Tests for my app and I've found a "speed bump" while writting them. While testing subclasses of *AndroidViewModel* im missing the **Application** parameter for its initialization. I've already read [this question that uses Robolectric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950654/androidviewmodel-and-unit-tests).

This is what I already tried so far:

- **Using Robolectric as the question describes**. As far as I understand, Robolectric can use your custom Application class for testing, the thing is im not using a custom application class as I dont need it. (the app is not that complex).
- **Using mockito**. Mockito throws an exception saying that the Context class cannot be mocked.
- **Using the InstrumentationRegistry**. I moved the test classes from the test folder to the androidTest folder, giving me access to the *androidTestImplementation* dependencies, I tried using the InstrumentationRegistry.getContext() and parse it to Application, of course this didn't worked, throwing a cast exception. I felt so dumb trying this but again, it was worth the shot.

I just want to instanciate my AndroidViewModel classes so I can call their public methods, but the Application parameter is needed. What can I do for this?

```
fun someTest() {
   val testViewModel = MyViewModelThatExtendsFromAndroidViewModel(**missing application parameter**)
   testViewModel.foo() // The code never reaches here as the testViewModel cant be initializated
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue, and found two solutions.

You can use **Robolectric** in a Unit Test, inside test directory, and choose the **platform Application** class.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(application = Application::class)
class ViewModelTest {

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun someTest() {
        val application = RuntimeEnvironment.application
        val testViewModel = MyViewModelThatExtendsFromAndroidViewModel(application)
        testViewModel.foo()
    }

}
```

Or you can use an *InstrumentationTest* inside androidTest directory, and cast the **InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().applicationContext** to **Application**:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ViewModelTest {

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun someTest() {
        val application = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext() as Application
        val testViewModel = MyViewModelThatExtendsFromAndroidViewModel(application)
        testViewModel.foo()
    }

}
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I made a small android project to test this code and works like a charm. Im making this the accepted answer, also, I added the project to a Github repository.

https://github.com/AlfredoBejarano/Android-Kotlin-Demos/tree/master/ViewModelTesting

again, thanks!

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/AlfredoBejarano/Android-Kotlin-Demos/tree/master/ViewModelTestingDemo

Comment: `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` is now deprecated instead, the much easier to read `ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()` may be used :-)