# Accessing appcontext in repository for shared preferences (Architecture)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am currently trying to wrap my head around the architecture components of the android platform, according to the official guide: 
[image]

In my app I currently need to store a list of strings (names) and access it in multiple places (activities as well as services). 2 possible approaches come to my mind:

1) store them comma-separated in the shared preferences.
2) create an entity and room-table with the name as only column.

I would prefer the first approach since I only need the names as one single string to perform a contains()-operation. using a room database seems to be more of a hassle for this purpose.

My concrete Question is: is it okay to store the appcontext in the repository-class (which is a singleton) or am I breaking any conventions/architectural rules? Or would it be better to actually use room for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the component architecture, and your `repository` needs to communicate with data sources that need a `context`, like room or `SharedPreferences` .. you'll need to extend your `ViewModel` from `AndroidViewModel` that will provide you a `context` that you can pass to your `repository` to use it to access the Room database or the `SharedPreferences`. there is no problem using a `context` in the repository, even if it is singleton, you already need it to access Room.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :). using AndroidViewModel seems to raise problems with testing, since I would not be able to perform normal UnitTests. Another solution that I thought of, would be to delegate the context from view to viewmodel to repository, but that does not seem like the best solution. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: no, you should not pass a context to the viewmodel because the viewmodel should not reference a view or context of activity, only the Application context .. in the official viewmodel documentation, google says "If the ViewModel needs the Application context, for example to find a system service, it can extend the AndroidViewModel class and have a constructor that receives the Application in the constructor, since Application class extends Context." and "A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context."

Comment: to test your AndroidViewModel class, you can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51650948/10256891