# How to test AndroidViewModel in unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, androidx, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to test ViewModel(AndroidViewModel parent), in unit tests(test folder) but when using

```
val application = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Application>()
```

it gives me this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
```

ExampleUnitTest

```
class ExampleUnitTest {
    private lateinit var myAndroidViewModel: MyAndroidViewModel
    private val app = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Application>()

    @Before
    fun init() {
        myAndroidViewModel = MyAndroidViewModel(app)
    }

    @Test
    fun addition_isCorrect() {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2)
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.3.0'
}
```

If I use robolectric, I no longer get said error, but I don't feel that it is a good option, since robolectric is more for ui test.

I hope you can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For Unit testing, one may want to use `@ActivityScoped` and then `@Inject` the `constructor` ...

---

But for testing `ViewModel` I'd rather use `androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel`:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha01'

  // When using Kotlin.
  kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'

  // When using Java.
  annotationProcessor 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'
}
```

Then one can `@ViewModelInject`:

```
class ExampleViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
  private val repository: ExampleRepository,
  @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
  ...
}
```

See [Hilt and Jetpack integrations](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack).

---

Here's another one [example](https://medium.com/@hamanhduy/test-your-android-mvvm-app-with-hilt-2ad583e49f74) using [Hilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt) with [MockK](https://mockk.io), which it's author summarizes as:

> Testing with Hilt, just `@UninstallModules` and then `@BindValue`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Robolectric** in a Unit Test, inside test directory, and choose the **platform Application** class.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(application = Application::class)
class ViewModelTest {

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun someTest() {
        val application = RuntimeEnvironment.application
        val testViewModel = MyAndroidViewModel(application)
        testViewModel.foo()
    }

}
```

Or you can use an *InstrumentationTest* inside androidTest directory, and cast the **InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().applicationContext** to **Application**:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ViewModelTest {

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun someTest() {
        val application = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext() as Application
        val testViewModel = MyAndroidViewModel(application)
        testViewModel.foo()
    }

}
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

For doing unit tests, **Mockito** library is a must (now use **MockK** for Kotlin).

So, for unit testing `AndroidViewModel`, we can `mock()` the `application` object like this:

```
val application = Mockito.mock(Application::class.java)
val viewModel = FirstViewModel(application)
```

- Helpful reading:
  [AndroidViewModel and Unit Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950654/androidviewmodel-and-unit-tests)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the tests with the target application's Application context, you can create your model for testing with

```kotlin
val app = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.applicationContext as Application
val model = YourModel(app)
// now run tests with model
```